# Can I use infinite numbers in a reduction?

Tags: computability, reductions, undecidability

I have to reduce $L_\text{empty}$ to $L_\text{inf}$

where

$\qquad L_\text{empty} = \{e \mid |L(P_e)| = 0 \}$ and
$\qquad L_\text{inf}= \{e \mid |L(P_e)| = \infty \}$.

where $P_e$ is the program with Gödel number $e$, and $L(P_e)$ the language it accepts.

So can I define a program $P$ like this

```
input n
Run Pe on 1...n for n steps
if Pe accepts any number then 
  enter an infinite loop and start accepting infinite number
if Pe does not accept any number then 
  accept 1
```

Now if I can define program P like above then asking the question whether the index of $P$ is in $L_\text{inf}$ will tell me whether the language accepted by $P_e$ is empty or not.

Comment: Hey, it not clear what you are asking for. You show a reduction that makes some sense. Do you want to know if this reduction is correct?

Comment: What is $P_{e}$? Is it meant to be a machine of some kind, a language, or a number? The wording suggests a machine, in which case, is your question "is checking for an infinite language decidable"?

Comment: Answer to your first line: sure you can. $P_{all}:$ "On input n: Accept". Then, $P_{all}$ accepts infinite many numbers (but each is finite).

Comment: e is the godel number ,so Pe is a program,L(Pe) means language accepted by the Program Pe

Comment: @Ran the logic of the program is that if the language accepted by Pe is infinite or finite then for every x there will exist a number such that Pe accept it within n steps and if it accepts any number then i am telling the program to go into an infinite loop and start accepting infinite number.If for all the inputs Pe do not accept any number ,then there does not exist any n for which program will go into infinite loop and hence for every input it will accept 1 which is finite

Comment: @LukeMathieson the logic of the program is that if the language accepted by Pe is infinite or finite then for every x there will exist a number such that Pe accept it within n steps and if it accepts any number then i am telling the program to go into infinite loop and start accepting infinite number.If for all the inputs Pe do not accept any input ,then there does not exist any n for which program will go into infinite loop and hence for every input it will accept 1 which is finite

Comment: @bourne please edit the question and try to be clear about what you want to know. So far, it's not a question but just a couple of statements.

Comment: I tried to clarify the question. I have still no idea what you would want with infinite numbers here.

Answer (score 3):

A language cannot contain infinite numbers, since by definitions it is a set of *finite* numbers. The language itself could be infinite, though: it could contain infinitely many numbers.

In your solution, in the first case, you first enter an infinite loop and then "start accepting infinite numbers", but once you've entered an infinite loop, you're not accepting anything.

Your reduction $f$ has to satisfy the following two properties:

- If $e \in L_{\mathrm{empty}}$ then $f(e) \in L_{\mathrm{inf}}$.
- If $e \notin L_{\mathrm{empty}}$ then $f(e) \notin L_{\mathrm{inf}}$.

In plain English:

- If $L_e$ accepts no inputs then $L_{f(e)}$ should accept infinitely many inputs.
- If $L_e$ accepts at least one input then $L_{f(e)}$ should accept finitely many inputs.

Try to see if you can come up with such a function $f$. The basic idea is similar to yours - on input $n$, $f(e)$ should check whether $L_e \cap \{1,\ldots,n\} \neq \emptyset$. You should just be more careful in what happens next.

Comment: I did not get what you said abt "A language cannot contain infinite numbers, since by definitions it is a set of finite numbers. The language itself could be infinite, though: it could contain infinitely many numbers."If Possible can you explain a little more,when we say that language accepted by this program is infinite does it not mean that the language is infinite,sorry i got confused

Comment: i can modify my line from "if Pe accept any number then enter an infinite loop and start accepting infinite number" to  "if Pe accept any number then accept n" but then this will also not work if language accepted by Pe is finite.Can you please tell the correct answer

Comment: i think i got it if i reverse the condition i.e if i accept all number n such that Pe does not accept any number from 1..n for n steps but accept only 1 if pe does accept any number from 1..n for n steps ,will that work

Comment: "Can you please tell me the correct answer?" No. You should find the correct answer yourself. "Will that work?" Once you've found the correct answer, prove that it's correct, and then you can be sure that it is correct.